# Removing/hiding minor ticks of a sliderInput in Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I wish to remove/hide minor ticks (not major tick) from `sliderInput()`. For example, in default example of Shiny app - Old Faithful Geyser Data, there is a `sliderInput()` to choose a number of bins for a histogram. Number of bins are always whole numbers. So it is good to hide/remove minor tick in `sliderInput()` and just show major ticks for bin numbers.

Default example of Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                 "Number of bins:",
                 min = 1,
                 max = 10,
                 value = 1)
      ),
  
     # Show a plot of the generated distribution
     mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
     )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
   # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
   x    <- faithful[, 2] 
   bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
  
   # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
   hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have tried `tick = FALSE` in `sliderInput()` like this:

```
sliderInput("bins", 
             label = "Number of bins:", 
             min = 1,
             max = 10,
             value = 1,
             ticks = FALSE)
```

But, this removes all the ticks (including major ticks) from `sliderInput()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can overwrite the CSS with `tags$style(type = "text/css", ".irs-grid-pol.small {height: 0px;}")`.
The CSS can be found here: https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/issues/171.

The resulting `sliderInput()` only displays the ticks for integers:

```
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", ".irs-grid-pol.small {height: 0px;}"),
    sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", 1, 10, 1)
  ),
  server <- function(input, output) {}  
)
```